# How can use scheduled task for live environment in mvc, c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, scheduled-tasks

I'm building a website using `mvc,c#`. In my case I use `xml` files to bind data.
`xml` file is download from the `web service`.it updates once a day.so I have to update the `xml` file (web service gets more time to load data) according to the `web service`. What I wrote  a method that will run on scheduled time each day.but most says it will not work fine in live environment. then I searched .most says to write `console application`.but I do not have idea how to use it with my project, and in live environment.what should I suppose to do.hope your help with this.

Comment: you don't really use it with the project, you just instruct Windows to run that code(that program) every 24 hours (with the built in Windows Scheduler). Anyway, I am running a schedule on a project and it works fine for what I am doing (just checking the state of something and sending some e-mails).

Comment: then how it contact with my project

Comment: well, the code in that small program will access your xml file and update it, as instructed by you, but that is, after all, a separate project / program and it doesn't really need to know about the existance of a main project, just like your main project doesn't need to know about this scheduled program... they both just do their job, whatever that is, and that's it... it's all they need to know :).

Comment: are there any tutorials or something like that how to implement it.it will helpful to others also

Comment: this is how you set up a task with windows task scheduler, the only thing you need to do is build that console application which I'm guessing you already know how to do :)... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a console application and use the built in Windows Scheduler to activate it. Windows Scheduler will deal with failure actions (logging, retry etc).